# Nginx how to redirect same location but different config for proxy_cache?

Tags: nginx

I have a proxy_cache for this location / with configs

```
location / {
    proxy_cache cache;
    proxy_cache_background_update on;
    proxy_cache_revalidate on;
    proxy_cache_min_uses    1;
    proxy_cache_valid       200     50m;
    proxy_cache_valid       404     1m;
    proxy_cache_use_stale   error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;  
    proxy_cache_lock        on;
    add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
    proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST;
    proxy_cache_key $scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$request_body$content_length;
    add_header Surrogate-Control "public, max-age=31536000, s-maxage=31536000";
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, s-maxage=31536000";
    proxy_ignore_headers Expires Set-Cookie Cache-Control X-Accel-Expires;

    ... some more codes...
}
```

That's for public access and work very well. Now i don't want office get cached. how can i modify these config without creating other Nginx server for my own office?

```
location / {
    ... if on IP addressess ...
     
    ... skip cache ...

    ... else : do cache ...

    ... some more codes...
}
```

Comment: I would try a named location for the cache configuration.